# Custom Font on Flutter

Tags: flutter, native

I have problem when I custom font on Flutter

My folder font

myapp/fonts/SairaSemiCondensed-Bold.ttf

here my pubspec.ymal

```
fonts:
 - family: SairaSemiCondensed
   fonts:
     - asset: fonts/fonts:SairaSemiCondensed-Bold.ttf
     weight: 700
```

I got error like this

```
Error on line 55, column 4 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a 

block mapping.
   fonts:
   ^

pub get failed (65)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should try google fonts package instead if your desired font is available at google fonts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
fonts:
 - family: SairaSemiCondensed
   fonts:
     - asset: fonts/fonts:SairaSemiCondensed-Bold.ttf
       weight: 700 # indented more
```

but it's more likely that the indentation of the whole block is wrong (or missing). Try to indent all lines in your questions one tab or 2 spaces more.

Indentation is significant in yaml.

Try to follow indentation exactly as shown in https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/fonts if my suggestion above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was coming up with me.
please recheck all lines in your `pubspec.yaml` file. it's  spaces issue.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the {:} colon in the fonts directory and write

```
fonts:
 - family: SairaSemiCondensed
   fonts:
     - asset: fonts/SairaSemiCondensed-Bold.ttf
       weight: 700 # indented more
```

INSTEAD