# I wanted to add this font to assets

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, flutter-pubspec

[image]

```yaml
assets:
   - assets/
       
   fonts:
     - family: Schyler
       fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  
    - family: Trajan Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
         weight: 700
```

I wanted to add this font to assets

Comment: When you're writing YAML, your indentation needs to be consistent. In this case, your indentation level of the first `- family:` line is not the same as the indentation level of the second.

Answer (score 1):

your indentation is not correct pubspec.yaml is giving error when you have wrong indentation in it give a tab space before

```
fonts:
```

check out this screen shot and make the indentation like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that the indentation of the whole block is wrong (or missing).

Read the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297935/custom-font-on-flutter).

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the exact indentation from `flutter`

```dart
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/

  fonts:
    - family: Schyler
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

here every dot represent single space

[image]

Check more about [adding assets-and-images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images).